# Find missing rows in a table without the MINUS operator

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have source & target table, so how can I calculate missing records in target table without using `minus` query in an Oracle database?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and explain what "missing record" means in your case.

Comment: @Gordan- hi missing records meant for records which are not transferred from source to target, like source has 10 records & target has 7,means 3 records are missing, i do not have data bt u can take any table suitable for this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why wouldn't you use `MINUS`?

This is simple:

```
SQL> select deptno from dept
  2  minus
  3  select deptno from emp;

    DEPTNO
----------
        40
```

This is more complicated:

```
SQL> select d.deptno from dept d
  2  where not exists (select null from emp e
  3                    where e.deptno = d.deptno);

    DEPTNO
----------
        40

SQL>
```

You said you don't want to use `MINUS`, but - you never said you don't want `INTERSECT`, so:

```
SQL> select d.deptno from dept d
  2  where d.deptno not in (select d1.deptno from dept d1
  3                         intersect
  4                         select e.deptno  from emp e);

    DEPTNO
----------
        40

SQL>
```

Or even

```
SQL> select d.deptno from dept d
  2  where d.deptno not in (select e.deptno from emp e
  3                         where e.deptno = d.deptno);

    DEPTNO
----------
        40

SQL>
```

Or this:

```
SQL> select d.deptno
  2  from dept d left join emp e on e.deptno = d.deptno
  3  where e.deptno is null;

    DEPTNO
----------
        40

SQL>
```

Comment: The `NOT EXISTS` solution is the best. `MINUS` will be much slower, since it requires a full ordering of both datasets (and, if the "first" table has duplicates, `MINUS` will remove them - so it may not even return the correct output). The `INTERSECT` solution is the worst - it does the same anti-join as the `NOT EXISTS` solution, plus the unnecessary and expensive `INTERSECT` operation.

Comment: I was kind of bored and tried to find as many options as I could. Not all of them are equal (as you know it, better than me, @mathguy; thank you for the comment).

Comment: Thank you Barbaros Özhan for detail answer, this is what i was looking for.

Comment: @rushikeshayati - Barbaros edited your question, but the Answer is by a different poster. Also, in addition to thanking Littlefoot for the answer, you should also mark it as Correct, so that others who will see this question will know it was the correct answer for your question.

Comment: @Littlefoot - No problem with showing several approaches, but it would help even more if you commented yourself on the reasons one may choose one over the other. The way the answer read (without my comment), one might conclude that any of those options was equally good. That's why I added my comment; I meant no direspect or disparaging of your answer.

Comment: @mathguy, I'm glad you posted the comment. You're absolutely right - I should have written something about those options, instead of just throwing them in one after another. Thank you, by all means.

Comment: @Littlefoot, heyy sorry for tht , actually i didnot c the name who answered, bdw thak you so  much for this